# A JavaScript exception occured: Cannot check the displayedness of a non-Element argument - error when trying to interact with webelements

Tags: selenium, safari, webdriver, ios-ui-automation, safaridriver

This exception occurs at the line of '.click()' , '.sendkeys() or any other actions that is about to perform on an element. Webelement is accessible but actions on those webelement throw the below exception. This issue is occurring only with SafariDriver. I couldnt find much information on the stackoverflow or other sites about this exception. Please share your findings on this. 
Appreciate your time and effort in reading my problem. Thanks in advance.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown error occurred: A JavaScript exception occured: Cannot check the displayedness of a non-Element argument.
Build info: version: '3.141.59'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '11.0.4'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: Safari, browserVersion: 13.1, javascriptEnabled: true, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, safari:automaticInspection: false, safari:automaticProfiling: false, safari:diagnose: false, safari:platformVersion: 10.14.6, safari:useSimulator: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, webkit:WebRTC: {DisableICECandidateFiltering: false, DisableInsecureMediaCapture: false}}


    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at testcases.SafariDesktop.performActions(SafariDesktop.java:39)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem on Java Selenium 3.141.59 when using the default sendkeys, resolved it by using the keyboard actions (Actions) like below:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

final WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.id("some_id"));;
new Actions(driver).click(webElement).perform();
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(webElement, "Hello World!").perform();
```

This solution works perfectly better than the simulation by Javascript (sometimes it insert the desired value in the targeted textfield but does not launch the expected events...)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, web elements doesn't respond to Webdriver commands and in this case, executing javascript command over the element worked.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element );
```